# Queries per day of youtube data api v3 is blank

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

Our app using google signing api already.
Now I'm trying to add a share-to-youtube function on this app.
I've added [Youtube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) to our API Service list.

When I enter the [Youtube Data API v3] page of our google api console, **[Queries per day] is blank.**

**Not 0 or 10000, blank.**
[image]
And my request with youtube api receives 403 error.

While I'm searching for the reason, I read that we have to fill the account's billing info so I've done it. But still the [Queries per day] value is blank.

To fix this problem, I sent [YouTube Data API Services – Exceptions form] and waiting for the answer.

**Usually how long it will takes to receive an answer for this form?**
**And would be there any other things that I can try to fix this problem?**

Comment: where did you find the **YouTube Data API Services – Exceptions form**?

Comment: When I click the pencil icon, limit editing popup show up. But my max limit was 0 on there. [apply for higher quota] on the top area of this popup linked me to that form.

Comment: If i remember correctly it took me a week or two to get the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the penile icon and increase the quota limit.  IMO its a bug that its default 0 and its been logged as an issue but they have yet to fix it.

You may also have to apply for an extension of your quota.   If you do it can take a few weeks.

You dont need billing with the Youtube data api its free to use.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll wait for the result of my apply.